# IdentityServer4 without HTTPS not working

Tags: angular, .net-core, identityserver4

I am currently busy implementing an SSO for multiple applications to use, so i`m using IdentityServer4 for the authentication.

Locally everything is working great, my angular apps are redirecting and authentication as it should and all is well in local-land...

For my Angular apps I am using angular-oauth2-oidc.

BUT..

Our internal test/QA environment is not accessible from the outside, and we cannot use HTTPS on that server, so I am trying to use it now without HTTPS(so just with plain http).
On the client side, I set the angular-oauth2-oidc setting requireHttps to false, so the initial redirect works, BUT, the moment I try to login, it does not redirect back to my application, and I cannot for the life of me get it to work!

Can someone please assist!

I know my RedirectUris and PostLogoutRedirectUris are set correctly, because it works if I use HTTPS...
But it seems as though the actual login section :

> await HttpContext.SignInAsync(userId, userName, props, claims);

might be giving problems, because if I check the logs, I see the following:

> IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint:Debug: Start
>   authorize callback request
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint:Debug: No user
>   present in authorize request
>   IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator:Debug: Start
>   authorize request protocol validation
>   IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore:Debug: client
>   configuration validation for client openIdConnectClient succeeded.
>   IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator:Debug: Calling
>   into custom validator:
>   IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
>   IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint:Information:
>   ValidatedAuthorizeRequest {   "ClientId": "openIdConnectClient",
>   "ClientName": "Example Implicit Client Application",   "RedirectUri":
>   "http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc",   "AllowedRedirectUris": [
>       "http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc"   ],   "SubjectId": "anonymous",   "ResponseType": "id_token token",   "ResponseMode":
>   "fragment",   "GrantType": "implicit",   "RequestedScopes": "openid
>   profile email Username EmailAddress",   "State":
>   "xGKOyXoYjiYtX22q3rwXLTni0V9HlgKrarR0lRNd",   "Nonce":
>   "xGKOyXoYjiYtX22q3rwXLTni0V9HlgKrarR0lRNd",   "Raw": {
>       "response_type": "id_token token",
>       "client_id": "openIdConnectClient",
>       "state": "xGKOyXoYjiYtX22q3rwXLTni0V9HlgKrarR0lRNd",
>       "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc",
>       "scope": "openid profile email Username EmailAddress",
>       "nonce": "xGKOyXoYjiYtX22q3rwXLTni0V9HlgKrarR0lRNd"   } } IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator:Information:
>   Showing login: User is not authenticated

I see the following lines:
No user present in authorize request

"SubjectId": "anonymous"

Showing login: User is not authenticated

Even if it finds the user, it still does that, so I think that might be the issue, but I have NO IDEA how to fix it ;(

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: *we cannot use HTTPS on that server* Um, why not? There's no reason not to use secure transport.

Comment: Business does not want to purchase a certificate for QA server, and a self-certified certificated keeps giving us the ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error

Comment: *Let's Encrypt* will give you free certificates and the self-certified issue you mention is easily fixable too.

Comment: I'm running IdentityServer in test  on http://internalServername/IDS,  so it is possible. Can you show part of the code that you make the login call with?

Comment: Are you running in an load balanced environment,  do you store the users in an database? I rely on third party authentication and I don't store users in an user store on the database,  with more server, you could be logged for the one and not for the other

Comment: I have a custom validator that looks up the users in a DB. It is not on a load balancer, but the testing environment is internal, so cannot be accessed from outsite.
Once I have the user, I do the HttpContext.SignInAsync call and then it should redirect back.

Comment: I have found a work around now, but its not ideal.
In my angular code, I capture the error that says the certificate is not valid. The application then opens a new tab for the identity server, so Chrome asks directly if it should add an exception.
Once that is done the user/tester is instructed to reopen the application.
Its not ideal, but it works...

Comment: I'm having same issue (running in localhost without https with the `dotnet run` command) and I think it might be possible that it is related to cookies. I will investigate more, but if Identityserver4 is setting cookies to be transmitted over HTTPS, then plain HTTP won't work